# Strange Behavior of Chrome Print - CSS Fix?

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering

***META:*** I asked this question over at [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117315/weird-mac-chrome-transparent-png-problems-when-printing), but they booted it, and told me to ask here. Apparently Webmasters only ever want to talk about SEO.
Original Post:

I am having a VERY strange issue with Chrome on the Mac.

I have this page: https://heartoflongislandna.org/cleantime/

It's a simple JS app that takes a date, calculates a time difference, then displays a bunch of mortised transparent PNG images that display awarded keytags. These overlap each other in two layouts:

Vertical, where one is laid over another in a vertical "chain," and

Horizontal, where they are placed side by side, but overlapping, like a spread out deck of cards.

What is happening, is that the layouts display (and print) fine in Safari and FF, but in Chrome, the print screws up. The screen display is fine, and looking at it with the device pane set to print also shows them fine.

There is also a small PNG image that is added to some of the images to close the ring at the top. That is added as a top, center background image.

The vertical layout is a bit better than the horizontal, in that the background transparency is honored, but the background image is lost (top keytag).

The horizontal layout is a mess. The background image is not displayed, and the background transparency is not honored.

I will add that examining this with Chrome's device view panel set to "Print" does not show a problem. It looks great. The print preview shows the issue, and opening the image in Preview also shows the problem, which is in the renderer.

***UPDATE 2:** This is now available as a fiddle, here: http://jsbin.com/kakirinife/edit?html,output

The (Fiddle) HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>CSS Issue Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /** This is the container for the keytag display. */
            .NACC-Keytags {
                margin-top: 122px;
                display: table;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            /** This allows us to compensate for the automatic offset of the tags. */
            .NACC-Keytag-Tabular {
                margin-top: 82px;
                padding-right: 50px;
                text-align:left;
            }

            /** This describes a keytag image layout. */
            .NACC-Keytag {
                width: 100px;
                max-width:100px;
                overflow: visible;
                margin-top:-122px;
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            /** If we are displaying a closed ring, then we add an image to the background. */
            .NACC-Keytag.NACC-Keytag-Ringtop {
                background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEYN.png');
                background-position: center top;
                background-size: 100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: local;
            }

            /** We display inline-block, so we get a flow that will wrap. */
            .NACC-Keytag-Tabular .NACC-Keytag {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-top:-82px;
                margin-right:-50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="NACC-Results">
            <div class="NACC-Keytags NACC-Keytag-Tabular">
                <img class="NACC-Keytag NACC-Keytag-Ringtop NACC-White-Tag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVIug.png">
                <img class="NACC-Keytag NACC-Keytag-Ringtop" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j11kj.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="NACC-Results">
            <div class="NACC-Keytags">
                <img class="NACC-Keytag NACC-Keytag-Ringtop NACC-White-Tag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVIug.png">
                <img class="NACC-Keytag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j11kj.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</body>
```

The Images:

[image: images/00_RingTop.png]
[image: images/01_Front.png]
[image: images/02_Front.png]

***UPDATE:*** I determined that this is likely a Chrome bug, and I reported it, but I am still looking for a CSS fix that I can apply. Chrome is a popular browser.

I will add images that show what happens.

First, this is the vertical format on the screen:

[image: Looks great!]

Next, here is the horizontal image on the screen:

[image: Shiny!]

Now, here are both of them as printed:

[image: Note missing background picture]

[image: Note opaque background and missing background picture]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: OK, but this is not a small amount of code. Remember that you asked for it. This is a supported extension (I wrote it), and it will be around for a while. I guess putting the code into a zip might work.

Comment: Hence the requirement for a **minimal** demo.

Comment: I'll work something out, but it may take some time.

Comment: I'm not sure if that improved things, but there you go.

Comment: Your post is now so huge that the actual problem is lost amongst a mass of images and "UPDATES". Can you condense it down to something easier to digest?

Comment: I'm working on it. I'm busy poring through the help center to find out if there's any way to render a full HTML page.

Comment: Use the snippet button (7th icon). It works similar to JSFiddle or CodePen. However, it is unlikely that we need to see the code for an entire page.

Comment: I got it. Gimme a minute. Thanks!

Comment: To address the missing ring-top you might consider changing from a background image defined in css to an actual image element. Browsers do not generally print background images by default. You could set the container as `relative position` and define the images in `absolute position` to get the placement you need.

Comment: Yeah, I hate to do that, because, in my experience, browsers have more problems with positioning than anything else, but I think that maybe that's been fixed by now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for posterity: Chrome has since fixed this bug.